# How can I remove a character {only found between curly brackets}, and take the brackets along for the ride?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, freebsd

For example, if I'm removing only spaces between brackets, the title of this post would be:

`How can I remove a character onlyfoundbetweenbrackets, and take the brackets along for the ride?`

I've only seen examples on here that leave the brackets in place.

**Edit:** I don't really need to remove spaces, I need to remove the **ñ** character.

Here's my code up until now, which is removes the **ñ**s, but sadly leaves the pesky curly brackets:

```
sed -i "" -e :1 -e 's/\({[^}]*\)[ñ]/\1/g;t1' file
_________________________________________________
ñañañañañañañaña{ñañañañañañañaña}batmañañañañañañañaña{ñañañañañañañaña}batmañ

getting:
ñañañañañañañaña{aaaaaaaa}batmañañañañañañañaña{ñañañañañañañaña}batmañ

but wishing for:
ñañañañañañañañaaaaaaaaabatmañañañañañañañaña{ñañañañañañañaña}batmañ
```

On FreeBSD/MacOS, so I'm unable to use gawk or GNU sed.

Comment: `and take the brackets along for the ride` ... what does this mean?

Comment: @jsotola looking for the brackets to also be removed

Comment: I'd expect you to get `ñañañañañañañaña{aaaaaaaa}batmañañañañañañañaña{aaaaaaaa}batmañ` with that code (both `{...}` to be processed, not just the first). Do you only want the first `{...}` or the first `{...}` with `ñ` inside, or all of them? Do you want `{`/`}`s to be removed even if they don't contain `ñ`s?

Comment: You messaged me on a different forum saying you want to have "no dependencies". Please edit your question here to clarify what you mean by that, e.g. do you mean using software that comes by default with MacOS (e.g. POSIX awk is OK and perl or python or ruby may or may not be OK, I don't know) or software that's mandatory by POSIX to exist on all Unix boxes (e.g. POSIX awk is OK but perl and python and ruby would not be OK) or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton, in any case, the OP's `-i ''` is not POSIX (it's a FreeBSD extension, incompatible with the `-i` extension of GNU's or other BSDs) so we can assume the OP is not concerned with POSIX compliance or portability.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the OP may have no idea that their existing code isn't portable, it's obviously not the final product, and they may be prototyping on a Mac code to run on some other platform, so we just don't know yet what they mean by "no dependencies" in this message they left me elsewhere: `I'm looking to have this app I'm working on end up with no dependencies (hence the hesitation to use gawk)` so all I'm asking for is the OP to clarify what that means to them.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '{
    while ( match($0,/\{[^}]+}/) ) {
        tgt = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
        gsub(/ñ/,"",tgt)
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}' file
ñañañañañañañañaaaaaaaaabatmañañañañañañañañaaaaaaaaabatmañ
```

The above assumes there are no nested brackets.

Comment: He wants to remove the curly brackets themselves and also, any space between them.

Comment: @NasirRiley oops, I missed that they need the brackets removed - fixed now, thanks. I don't see anything about needing to also remove spaces in the question but if they need that it's an obvious trivial tweak to the regexp in the gsub().

Comment: He says in the question that he wants to remove the spaces between the brackets and gives and example of this using the question itself as an example. Notice the lack of spaces.

Comment: They initially say `if I'm removing only spaces` and then show the output for that given the subject line as input, but then they go on to give a full example removing `ñ`s instead and gives the input `ñañañañañañañaña{ñañañañañañañaña}batmañ` which is why there are no spaces in the output, because there are none in the input. The question is clearly about removing **a character**, whether that's a space or `ñ` or some other character, not multiple different characters.

Comment: I didn't mention anything about multiple or different characters. This initial example that he gave had the character as a space. To you, it may be as simple as changing something in the code but perhaps it isn't to him. This is why it's important to explain the different parts of what you are doing so that it's clear rather than stating that it's an obvious trivial tweak that you assume the person understands.

Comment: You said `and also, any space...` - i.e. a space in addition to the existing characters. I'm not going to explain how to replace a `ñ` with a space or any other character, nor am I going to explain basic awk syntax that's clearly described in the manual in every answer I provide. A few seconds of thought and maybe a glance at the manual is all that's required to understand and/or modify the script I posted.

Comment: @NasirRiley and Ed Morton I updated the question to be clearer, and the example to show that I do have multiple sets of brackets per line

Comment: @Joe I updated my answer to handle multiple pairs of brackets on each line.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`, assuming those `ñ` are UTF-8 encoded and handling both the precomposed and decomposed versions of that character:

```bash
perl -C -pi -e '
  BEGIN {
    $c = qr{\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE}|n\N{COMBINING TILDE}}
  }
  s<\{([^}]*$c[^}]*)\}><$1 =~ s/$c//gr>ge' -- your-file
```

(it assumes that there are no nested `{...}`s).

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed to work on gawk/mawk/mawk2/nawk, works just as fine in either UTF8 or POSIX/C locales

Condensed version :

```
 gawk/mawk/nawk 'BEGIN {
       __=index(FS="[{"(OFS="")"}]","{") 
     } __<=(NF=NF) {        _=!__
  do { gsub("\303\261","",$(_+=__)) } while(_<NF) }__'
```

Expanded out :

```
ñañañañañañañañaaaaaaaaabatmañañañañañañañañaaaaaaaaabatmañ

# gawk profile, created Thu Mar 17 08:27:40 2022

# BEGIN rule(s)

BEGIN {
 1      __ = index(FS = "[{" (OFS = "") "}]", "{")
}

# Rule(s)

 1  __ <= (NF = NF) { # 1
 1      _ = ! __
 3      do {
 3          gsub("\303\261", "", $(_ += __))
    } while (_ < NF)
}

 1  __ { # 1
 1      print
}
```

- found minor bug, fixed via `NF=NF`